# Using multiple custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I´m trying to achieve a grouped styled UITableView like the Contact apps detailedView. I want the top most cell to be transparant and have a UISegemtedControl at the bottom.

When I try to create two different types of custom cells, only the first one is loaded even though i use two different cellIdentifiers.

Would appreciate som guidance. Or some good tutorial tips for the same topic.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /*
    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;
    [backView release];
    */

    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"DetailCellStyle1";
    static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"DetailCellStyle2";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        // Load from nib
        DetailCellViewController *cell = (DetailCellViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        loadNibNamed:@"DetailCellView" 
                                        owner:nil 
                                        options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                    cell = (DetailCellViewController *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }
    else  {
        // Load from nib
        DetailCellViewController2 *cell = (DetailCellViewController2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        loadNibNamed:@"DetailCellView" 
                                        owner:nil 
                                        options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                    cell = (DetailCellViewController2 *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What does your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method return?

Comment: Okay, I was assuming that you perhaps had only one section with two rows... Looking at your code again, I notice that you load cell 1 and cell 2 in exactly the same way by taking the first object of type `UITableViewCell` in the "DetailCellView" nib. Therefore, you're getting the same cell in both cases.

Comment: @omz cheers mate that did it. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load cell 1 and cell 2 in exactly the same way by taking the first object of type `UITableViewCell` in the "DetailCellView" nib. Therefore, you're getting the same cell in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to honest I am not sure either, but, the load call only apears to be efficiant, when the cell is nil, maybe try to load the second as a else in of the  `if(cell == nil)` call... because in the end of the code, you are setting it nil again ... so maybe :-)

Comment: so, I missread your code, in your first section you want to have different cells, than in your other sections ... so what are your different nibs are called like, because, you are telling the load nib, to look for "DetailCellView" both times