# Using multiple custom UITableViewCells in uitableview

Tags: objective-c

please go throgh the link 
[Using multiple custom UITableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982419/using-multiple-custom-uitableviewcells)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return nil;
}
```

here 
i have not understand why you have added 
return nil before the end of the braces.

Answer (score 1):

You should never return nil from `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I believe that programmer was using it to indicate an unreachable code path, and to prevent the compiler from complaining that control had reached the end of the function without returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong indentation in that code.

Here is the right indentation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /*
    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;
    [backView release];
    */

    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"DetailCellStyle1";
    static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"DetailCellStyle2";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        // Load from nib
        DetailCellViewController *cell = (DetailCellViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        loadNibNamed:@"DetailCellView" 
                                        owner:nil 
                                        options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                    cell = (DetailCellViewController *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }
    else  {
        // Load from nib
        DetailCellViewController2 *cell = (DetailCellViewController2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        loadNibNamed:@"DetailCellView" 
                                        owner:nil 
                                        options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                    cell = (DetailCellViewController2 *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

There is the else that `return cell`;